# Can my application be vulnerable because of an oudated Docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, snyk

Currently, my company wants to ensure that everything is secure, and now I'm doing some tests to verify that our Docker containers achieve this.

My first concern comes in after I realized that after running `docker scan ...` (that uses Snyk) a Critical vulnerability was found, regarding curl(curl/libcurl4@7.74.0-1.3).

The obvious fix to this was to add to the Dockerfile some scripting to delete that version and then do a manual update using the latest curl release, problem fixed right? Appears that isn't ...

After doing a second scan with the updated docker image, the same outdated versions keep appearing, and this is very strange because we should see the new curl version no?

So my specific doubt here is:

Q - No matter what we do, we always carry the dependencies that came in with the (pre-built)docker image?

This is the base image that I'm using: php:8.0-apache

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, the image will always use the dependencies that are built into it, and yes, this brings another path where you need to take updates (rebuild images with current versions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you update the image adding the instructions with the update as you mentioned (assuming the latest release of curl addressed that issue), Snyk should reflect the changes.

I'd suggest logging a support ticket for further technical investigation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think that this was an issue with Bitbucket pipelines, so I ended up doing these steps: Moving all the installation commands from BB pipelines to the Dockerfile(selecting specific versions E.g. curl=7.83.1-r2), then to avoid any cache I added the --no-cache=true to the docker build command, and then I did another scan with Snyk and it seems like the problem is fixed :)

Comment: You're welcome and nicely done. Glad the issue was resolved.